# In a C# application all threads randomly pause execution for multiple seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, pause

We have an application that runs continuously. It is comprised of a TCP/IP connect and < 30 threads. At random intervals (maybe once every 2 to 3 weeks) all executing thread pause.  The pause can range from 2 to 6 seconds.  I have never seen this before and can't find anything online that might explain what would cause this behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: That sounds like a GC pause. What is the memory usage like here?

Comment: my guess would be that the Garbage collector might be the reason but you should look into log files and if you don't find anything in there, do a lot more logging.

Comment: Something else happening on the machine? I always used to find loading an optical disc into my machine paused everything, in every app, for a moment

Comment: There are large chunks of memory allocated and dropped (~200mb) but overall memory usage is stable. We had a GC problem before but optimized the code to remove it. overall memory usage is < 15% for the whole computer.  We upped the logging and what we see is all logs stop wring for the paused time, location of the pause int the code is not consistent.  We planned on writing a small application that logs ever 0.5 seconds to see if it pauses as well to eliminate a computer issue.

Comment: Any update? I have the same problem with one thread that randomly stops execution between 500ms to 3-4 seconds. The thread normally sleeps for 200ms.